# ASP.NET -Retrieving a list of images from the Database and display them in the view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to retrieve a list of images from the database and display them on the view. All the images are stored in 'image' data type format in the database. Below are my controller, view model, and View. I'm not sure if it is correct, so please help. I've just used Linq2SQL since it's just a sample project. Please correct my code, and help me how to display a list of images on the view. I'm just a beginner, so it'd be great if you could please keep the solution straight and simple.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public int imageId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> imageList { get; set; }     
}
```

**Controller:** **(Updated and Solved)**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
{

    var imagesList = (from q in ctx.Images
                      select new Models.ImageViewModel
                      {
                      imageId = q.id
                      }).ToList();

    IEnumerable<int> imageIds = imagesList.Select(x=>x.imageId);
    Models.Test obj = new Models.Test();
    obj.imageList = imageIds;
    return View(obj);
}

    public ActionResult View(int imageId)
    {
        byte[] imageArray = (from q in ctx.Images
                             where q.id == imageId
                             select q.data.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault(); 
        return File (imageArray,"image/jpg");
    }
```

**View:**

```
   @model MvcApplication3.Models.ImageViewModel

   @foreach (var id in Model.imageList)
{ 
    <img src="@Url.Action("View", "Home", new { imageId = id},null)" />
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I can't see any images at all. Just a list of small boxes with 'X' marks in them.

Comment: I also think my logic might be wrong. Please feel free to provide me an alternative solution to perform this. Thanks

Comment: There is no property called `bitimage` in your view model but you refer to it in your view. Do you have a handler or action to download the image itself? Remember that the `src` attribute of `img` expects a URL to an image, not an image itself.

Comment: sorry.I've updated my code now. I renamed the property name bitimage to ImageStream. Forgot to update that when I copied the code here. my apologies.

Comment: That won't work - a Stream isn't a URL.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any other ways of how to get it working ? Could you please post a code snippet ?

Comment: Follow Britton's advice below - you need to build an action to download each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Britton recommended this as well but I'll reiterate.

You should have two actions/views to achieve what you want. One to retrieve a single image, and another that is a list of all images using the action mentioned before to retrieve a single image.

Here's a very rough example of what I mean. I haven;t tested this to ensure it compiles but it should give you a rough idea of how to do this.

```
class ImageLibrary
}
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        //I'm going to assume here you have some sort of service or repository for obtaining your images at this point.
        //This doesn't retrieve the actual image data, just the metadata. It's less of a hit on the DB this way
        var imagesList = imageService.ListAllImages()
        IEnumerable<int> imageIds = imagesList.Select(x=>x.ImageId)
        return View("List", imageIds)
    }

    public ActionResult View(int imageId)
    {
        var image = imageService.GetImage(imageId);

        var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition() { FileName = image.Name, Inline = true };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
        return File(image.Data, image.ContentType); //including content type since I'm assuming the image could be a jpg, gif, png, etc./
    }

}
```

And in the `ImageLibrary/List` view.

```
@foreach(var id in Model)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("View", "ImageLibrary", new {imageId = id})">
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Could you explain what the imageService does ? Like i've mentioned, I'm a beginner in MVC, and I think this is a bit too advanced for me. I know how to access data by mapping them to viewmodel (as written in my controller), but haven't started using repositories yet. I've completed the first action, and it looks good thus far.

Answer (score 4):

Make a new action that takes a unique identifier for your image, use the ID to get a `byte[]` from your database then write it directly to the response stream like this

```
Response.ContentType = "content type of your image";
//filecontents is the byte[]
Response.BinaryWrite(filecontents);
```

Then whenever you need to display an image from your database you set the source like this

```
<img src="/Controller/Action/ImageId"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to send a request to retrieve a specific image. I just would like to grab a bunch of images from the database and display it to the user. Similar to displaying a list of all the employees in an employee table. Could you please have a look at my controller and view model again, and see if anything is wrong there ?

Comment: Once you have this action to retrieve a specific image all you need is a list of image Ids. Then in your view loop through the list of IDs and build the image tags like I did above.

Comment: Cool. will give it a try now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you get the data as a base64 string, if so you could try:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@(item.bitimage)" alt="test.png" />
```

failing that try:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@ToBase64String(item.bitimage)" alt="test.png" />
```

http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your code, but still no luck. Could you please have a look at my controller and view model, and see if something is wrong there ?

Comment: what if you use item.image?

Comment: Be warned that this is a bad approach for anything but the very smallest images as it will slow down you page load and stop your browser caching any images.

Comment: Indeed it does put all the load on a single request, I can imagine how that could ramp up, I would suggest Britton's approach.

Comment: As I can't comment on his approach due to rep level, just create the controller and in your list view have it display an image tag with the id for each instance.